Error con Adw.PreferencesDialog al cerrar la ventana
Mi aplicación da este error al cerrar la ventana de preferencias Adw.PreferencesDialog:
(multiplicar:2): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 13:17:43.002: Widget of type “Preferencias” already has an accessible role of type “GTK_ACCESSIBLE_ROLE_GENERIC”

Si intento abrirla otra vez la aplición se cierra.
Este es el código desde el que abro la ventana:
    def on_preferences_action(self, _action, _param):
        print(self.preferencias)
        if self.preferencias is None:
            self.preferencias = Preferencias() # Adw.PreferencesDialog
        self.preferencias.present()

La primera vez que llamo a la acción la ventana se abre correctamente y print(self.preferencias) imprime None como es de esperar.
Si cierro la ventana es cuando aprece el error:
(multiplicar:2): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 13:17:43.002: Widget of type “Preferencias” already has an accessible role of type “GTK_ACCESSIBLE_ROLE_GENERIC”

Si lo intento abrir de nuevo la aplicación se cierra y print(self.preferencias) imprime <preferencias.Preferencias object at 0x7fc85cf66780 (Preferencias at 0x586889a2a3d0)> por lo que supongo que el problema es que el diálogo no se destryue al cerrarlo.
Si intento self.preferencias.present(self.win) siendo self.win la ventana principal Adw.ApplicationWindow el resultado es el mismo.
Si intento self.preferencias.get_parent().set_hide_on_close(True). El error persiste pero funciona aunque no creo que esta se la manera correcta.
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?
